# Print characters number of times as given in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures

I have string `"A3B2C3D4"`  it should be printed in output like following

```
AAABBCCCDDDD
```

How can this be achieved in ruby?

Comment: What have you tried[?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113530/print-characters-number-of-times-as-given-in-string)

Comment: How can this question get upvoted?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "How can this be achieved in ruby?" – You can achieve it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"A3B2C3D4".scan(/(\D+)(\d+)/).map { |c, i| c * i.to_i }.join
#⇒ "AAABBCCCDDDD"
```

Comment: This is so great, How can I get the array [["A", "3"], ["B", "2"], ["C", "3"], ["D", "4"]] without using scan?

Comment: @Prem by iterating through the string chars and collecting results.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "A3B2C3D4"
str.gsub(/([A-Z])(\d)/) { $1 * $2.to_i } #=> "AAABBCCCDDDD"
```

Comment: `str.tap { |str| while str[/(\D)(\d+)/] do str[/(\D)(\d+)/] = $1 * $2.to_i end }` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
t =[]; 
# scan for each letter and split, then combine the array by each two elements. Get the desired output
("A3B2C3D4".scan /\w/).each_slice(2).to_a.each {|g| t<< [g.first * g.last.to_i]}
t.flatten.join
=> "AAABBCCCDDDD"
```

A bit verbose.

Comment: `to_a.each` is superfluous here. Moreover avoid using an external array that you use to fill with each iteration, that's what `map` is for. Your answer can also be refactored to `("A3B2C3D4".scan /\w/).each_slice(2).map { |a, b| a * b.to_i }.join`. By which point it gets dangerously close to another answer already posted.

Comment: Also there's no need for the `;`!

Comment: True. That's why I wrote this was a bit verbose. And I forgot to remove the semicolon, I had it all in one-line earlier ;)

Comment: And I chose `to_a` because it was easier to visualize what is happening than to say map invokes the given block for each element and returns in the same place. Took liberty in a public forum. No harm in brevity though. Cheers!